# What bird is this (found at Alice Springs Desert Park in Australia)?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I was reviewing photographs of the animals we found on our trip to Australia during the past September and I cannot find what is the bird in the picture. It was found inside Alice Springs Desert Park, so it has to be a native bird, same as all the others.

[image]

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I'm tempted to say it could be a golden-headed cisticola (*Cisticola exilis*), but it's a difficult angle to clearly see the head.

Comment: Thank you @cezar it totally looks like this one, the habitat matches and I've searched in several photos on flicker and google and it seems like the bird :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a *Cisticola exilis* as stated by @cezar
If someone has any objection please reopen this.

Comment: Thanks and sorry @theforestecologist I'll take that into account next time!